# How can wait until ansible script execute in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ansible

I am working on nodejs + ansible module, our module call ansible script, then ansible script will execute the process in remote machine. Finally I render ansible result and view via fontend. while execute the ansible script, browser goes to **connection was reset.**

**my code:**

```
 app.post('/create', function (req, res) {

  var playbook = new Ansible.Playbook().playbook("m2install");
    playbook.on('stdout', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    playbook.on('stderr', function (data) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    var command = playbook.inventory('inventories/M2Install/hosts').verbose('v');
    var promise = command.exec();
    promise.then(function (successResult) {
        tmp += "Create Magento Setup";
        tmp += successResult.output;
        fs.unlink('roles/install/vars/main.yml', function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('delete docker_variables.yml file ');
            } else {
                console.log('Not delete docker_variables.yml file');
            }
        });
        res.render("result", {data: tmp, title: "Magento Setup  Report"});
    }, function (error) {
        tmp += error;
        res.render("result", {data: tmp, title: "Magento Setup  Report"});
    });

  });


  app.post('/setup', function (req, res) {

      postcount = Object.keys(req.body).length
      console.log(postcount);

      for (var key in req.body) {

          console.log(req.body[key]);

          if (req.body[key] == "create") {
              res.render('create', {title: 'Magento Setup Form'});
              sucesscount++;
          }
          });
```

**My ansible playbook:**

```
---

- name: Build image and with buildargs
    docker_image:
       path: /opt/test/dockerfiles/mysql
       name: mysql

  - name: Build image and with buildargs
    docker_image:
       path: /opt/test/dockerfiles/nginx
       name: php_nginx

  - name: Create  Mysql Docker Container
    command: docker run -it -d --name m2_node_mysql --privileged mysql

  - name: Create  php+ nginx Docker Container
    command: docker run -it -d --name php_nginx  --privileged php_nginx
```

**my ansible logs:**

```
         mysql
  Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file


  PLAY [webservers] **************************************************************


  TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

  ok: [192.168.1.101]


  TASK [mysql : Install Docker py] ***********************************************

  changed: [192.168.1.101] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["pip", "install", "docker-py"], "delta": "0:00:01.409080", "end": "2017-08-01 11:15:19.196183", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-08-01 11:15:17.787103", "stderr": "You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.", "stderr_lines": ["You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.", "You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command."], "stdout": "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docker-py in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.5.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): websocket-client>=0.32.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3==1.15.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.2->docker-py)", "stdout_lines": ["Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docker-py in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.5.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): websocket-client>=0.32.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3==1.15.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.2->docker-py)"]}


  TASK [mysql : Build Mysql image and with buildargs] ****************************

  1
  mysql
  Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file


  PLAY [webservers] **************************************************************


  TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

  ok: [192.168.1.101]


  TASK [mysql : Install Docker py] ***********************************************

  changed: [192.168.1.101] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["pip", "install", "docker-py"], "delta": "0:00:00.282909", "end": "2017-08-01 11:17:09.426975", "rc": 0, "start": "2017-08-01 11:17:09.144066", "stderr": "You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.\nYou should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.", "stderr_lines": ["You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.", "You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command."], "stdout": "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docker-py in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.5.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): websocket-client>=0.32.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)\nRequirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3==1.15.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.2->docker-py)", "stdout_lines": ["Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docker-py in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.5.2 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): websocket-client>=0.32.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from docker-py)", "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3==1.15.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.5.2->docker-py)"]}


  TASK [mysql : Build Mysql image and with buildargs] ****************************

  changed: [192.168.1.101] => {"actions": ["Built image m2_node_mysql_test2:latest from /opt/magento2/dockerfiles/mysql"], "changed": true, "image": {"Architecture": "amd64", "Author": "", "Comment": "", "Config": {"ArgsEscaped": true, "AttachStderr": false, "AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": false, "Cmd": ["mysqld"], "Domainname": "", "Entrypoint": ["docker-entrypoint.sh"], "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "GOSU_VERSION=1.7", "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6", "MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.37-1debian8"], "ExposedPorts": {"3306/tcp": {}}, "Hostname": "e24d0b5cccc1", "Image": "sha256:c314e2de3d08e55873356869f05407e24586510110b1f95ff0e27a694b0608ed", "Labels": {}, "OnBuild": [], "OpenStdin": false, "StdinOnce": false, "Tty": false, "User": "", "Volumes": {"/var/lib/mysql": {}}, "WorkingDir": ""}, "Container": "144eb23225ba2e493f3918cfd02e8c4c1a810df5f50cc55cb9c3925436efec5a", "ContainerConfig": {"ArgsEscaped": true, "AttachStderr": false, "AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": false, "Cmd": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "#(nop) CMD [\"mysqld\"]"], "Domainname": "", "Entrypoint": ["docker-entrypoint.sh"], "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "GOSU_VERSION=1.7", "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6", "MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.37-1debian8"], "ExposedPorts": {"3306/tcp": {}}, "Hostname": "e24d0b5cccc1", "Image": "sha256:c314e2de3d08e55873356869f05407e24586510110b1f95ff0e27a694b0608ed", "Labels": {}, "OnBuild": [], "OpenStdin": false, "StdinOnce": false, "Tty": false, "User": "", "Volumes": {"/var/lib/mysql": {}}, "WorkingDir": ""}, "Created": "2017-08-01T05:54:47.287482027Z", "DockerVersion": "1.10.3", "GraphDriver": {"Data": {"DeviceId": "3240", "DeviceName": "docker-253:3-11010052-6d8fd3972362865502b6e401c81da0ddcb39058e379c008aeae17b382046b81c", "DeviceSize": "10737418240"}, "Name": "devicemapper"}, "Id": "sha256:b9a84cf1b66bd54dd24b92171ee7b5e52566bf1dfea5756ca7ae07736080e948", "Os": "linux", "Parent": "sha256:c314e2de3d08e55873356869f05407e24586510110b1f95ff0e27a694b0608ed", "RepoDigests": [], "RepoTags": ["m2_node_mysql_test2:latest"], "Size": 298292364, "VirtualSize": 298292364}}


  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

  192.168.1.101              : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   



  changed: [192.168.1.101] => {"actions": ["Built image m2_node_mysql_test2:latest from /opt/magento2/dockerfiles/mysql"], "changed": true, "image": {"Architecture": "amd64", "Author": "", "Comment": "", "Config": {"ArgsEscaped": true, "AttachStderr": false, "AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": false, "Cmd": ["mysqld"], "Domainname": "", "Entrypoint": ["docker-entrypoint.sh"], "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "GOSU_VERSION=1.7", "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6", "MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.37-1debian8"], "ExposedPorts": {"3306/tcp": {}}, "Hostname": "e24d0b5cccc1", "Image": "sha256:a0c53461849600d1ee4bfa7be732beb49470e961fce46e42853489b68317a6ec", "Labels": {}, "OnBuild": [], "OpenStdin": false, "StdinOnce": false, "Tty": false, "User": "", "Volumes": {"/var/lib/mysql": {}}, "WorkingDir": ""}, "Container": "c09b76549dc03e5ae0cb046853f0dd63f053ae9c8b47c6563a94220d87f56b3e", "ContainerConfig": {"ArgsEscaped": true, "AttachStderr": false, "AttachStdin": false, "AttachStdout": false, "Cmd": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "#(nop) CMD [\"mysqld\"]"], "Domainname": "", "Entrypoint": ["docker-entrypoint.sh"], "Env": ["PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", "GOSU_VERSION=1.7", "MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6", "MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.37-1debian8"], "ExposedPorts": {"3306/tcp": {}}, "Hostname": "e24d0b5cccc1", "Image": "sha256:a0c53461849600d1ee4bfa7be732beb49470e961fce46e42853489b68317a6ec", "Labels": {}, "OnBuild": [], "OpenStdin": false, "StdinOnce": false, "Tty": false, "User": "", "Volumes": {"/var/lib/mysql": {}}, "WorkingDir": ""}, "Created": "2017-08-01T05:55:47.56392089Z", "DockerVersion": "1.10.3", "GraphDriver": {"Data": {"DeviceId": "3262", "DeviceName": "docker-253:3-11010052-41d504d5ad8375f1f76d2af19a133982e189b31baeecfd775a133842cdbf0432", "DeviceSize": "10737418240"}, "Name": "devicemapper"}, "Id": "sha256:b8903c8b02f2b88db1a0b7ae9cbcfdd80188f63f37c5430167cf7e946069348b", "Os": "linux", "Parent": "sha256:a0c53461849600d1ee4bfa7be732beb49470e961fce46e42853489b68317a6ec", "RepoDigests": [], "RepoTags": ["m2_node_mysql_test2:latest"], "Size": 298292364, "VirtualSize": 298292364}}


  PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

  192.168.1.101              : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**I need to wait nodejs until ansible script execute.**

**Note:** Node js called my ansible module twice, see my `ansible log`, Suggest Me Why? if node call second time ansible module, browser goes to **Connection was reset.**

Suggest Me, how to do that and How to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you try adding "playbook.on('stdout', function(data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
playbook.on('stderr', function(data) { console.log(data.toString()); });
var promise = playbook.exec();" to see if ansible is terminating abnormally?

Comment: @Petro026  I add this two line its will generate ansible running logs. nodejs call ansible script multiple times. why?

Comment: @Petro026 I updated My logs

Comment: can you post the entire route function?

Comment: Can you post the install playbook you're using?

Comment: @ChrisLam I update my full controller

Comment: @Petro026 I updated my ansible playbook